# JavaScript optional destructuring argument in function

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have this function signature

```
const foo = (arg, { opt1, opt2, opt3 }) => {
   ...
};
```

but I'd like to have this second argument optional, such as calling the function like

```
foo("Hello");
```

However, I get

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `opt1` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

So, I'm tempted to fix this with changing the function such as :

```
const foo = (arg, options = {}) => {
   const { opt1, opt2, opt3 } = options;

   ...
};
```

But was wondering if there was a more inline alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could assign a default object and take a destructuring at the same time.

The result is `undefined` for all three destructured properties, if no second parameter or `undefined`.

```
const foo = (arg, { opt1, opt2, opt3 } = {}) => {
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do:-

```js
const foo = (arg, { opt1, opt2, opt3 } = {}) => {

   ...
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this `{ opt1, opt2, opt3 } = {}`  when declaring the function.